# Component doesn't update after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I use a dictionary to store the likes of posts in every card.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    like_dict: {}
  };
  this.likeClicked = this.likeClicked.bind(this)
}
```

I have a like button on every card and the text denotes the number of likes.

```
<Button transparent onPress={() => {this.likeClicked(poid, 0)}}>
    <Icon name="ios-heart-outline" style={{ color: 'black' }} />
</Button>
<Text>{this.state.like_dict[poid]}</Text>
```

The `likedClicked` function looks like this. I set the state of `like_dict`, but the text above won't rerender.

```
likeClicked(poid, liked){
  var like_dict_tmp = this.state.like_dict
  if (liked){
    like_dict_tmp[poid] -= 1
  }else{
    like_dict_tmp[poid] += 1
  }
  this.setState({
    like_dict: like_dict_tmp
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the key principles of React is never mutate the state directly.

When you do `var like_dict_tmp = this.state.like_dict`, `like_dict_tmp` is referencing the same object in the state so altering `like_dict_tmp` will mutate the state directly, so the subsequent `setState` will not update the component.

You can create a shallow copy with `var like_dict_tmp = { ...this.state.like_dict }` or replace the whole function with:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  like_dict: {
    ...prevState,
    [poid]: (prevState[poid] || 0) + (liked ? 1 : -1),
  },
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for notifying me that. I tried the approach but it still doesn't update.

Comment: Does it not update at all, or does it not uodate as expected? One problem I can envision is that in your constructor you don't define poid, and then you try to add/subtract from it in your likeClicked method

Comment: Did you try my `setState` code block above? In your original code you did not provide a default value when `prevState[poid]` is `undefined` so doing `undefined + 1` will always return `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the state before modifying it. What you are doing is just creating a link to the state in like_dict_tmp (either use what I am doing below, or use concat with an empty array):

`var like_dict_tmp = this.state.like_dict.concat([])`

```
likeClicked(poid, liked) {
  var like_dict_tmp = this.state.like_dict.slice()
  if (liked) {
    like_dict_tmp[poid] -= 1
  } else {
    like_dict_tmp[poid] += 1
  }
  this.setState({
    like_dict: like_dict_tmp
  })
}
```

Also, {} is an object in JS, and is not typically called a dictionary

Comment: If you want to know more, look at this link https://codeburst.io/javascript-passing-by-value-vs-reference-explained-in-plain-english-8d00fd06a47c, in particular primitives vs objects and passing by reference vs. passing by value.